# jquery targeting nested #div

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am web-designer, not a programmer and  a newbie in Javascript / jQuery (although I do have experience with PHP )

I am having a problem understanding why I can not seem to target the right div for a hover effect.

Fiddle is here :
http://jsfiddle.net/obmerk99/F6wJs/

When I target a certain div class (.mas), the effect works just fine
But when I target a second div class (.meta2 - absolute positioned within the boundaries of the first -  .mas ) the effect does not work.

(plain words - I want the effect to be triggered by the thumb, and not by the large image.)

the code is the same, so it is not a syntax error - I am sure I am missing something fundamental about understanding jQUery.

Care to explain ??

EDIT I :

After understanding what @Rick explained - I must say that my problem was a bit more complicated , I just posted the simple version because i thought it is enough.

The real markup has MORE than one element of the said classes.

If I remove ",this" from the code, it will trigger ALL of them ..

New Fiddle Here :
http://jsfiddle.net/obmerk99/F6wJs/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is actually on the fade-in. In the JQuery in your fiddle, you have things like:

```
jQuery(".meta",this).fadeIn(400);
```

That tells JQuery to look for `.meta` **within** `this`, and the keyword `this` is here referring to the JQuery object returned by the outer selector.

In other words, if your outer selector is `.mas`, JQuery only searches for `.meta` within `.mas`. If the outer selector is `.meta2`, it only searches for `.meta` within `.meta2`. And, of course, `.meta` is within `.mas`, but it is not within `.meta2`, hence the issue you're having.

This can be fixed by simply removing the second parameter (`this`) from each fade call. So the line earlier becomes:

```
jQuery(".meta").fadeIn(400);
```

The updated fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/qsQWU/1/

**Edit:**

As pointed out by the other answers and the question edit (thanks for the heads-up), I wasn't thinking about the possibility of this needing to be done on multiple elements individually. They are correct; the above solution will not work for that scenario. Their alternatives work, but I also want to offer a third possibility: replacing `this` with `jQuery(this).parent()`, so that the context just becomes one level higher.

The new fiddle, modified from the question edit, is here: http://jsfiddle.net/GU8Bj/

Comment: Thank you rick for your quick response - I understand that . Please read my edit I with the new fiddle . I was trying to be minimalistic in my question. sorry about that . (I will except your answer anyhow because you explained the right thing - but I would still like to know how to resolve this - in order to understand the selctor process..)

Comment: @ObmerkNinenine No, that is my fault for not considering the possible use cases. Anyway, I've edited in a better solution, while trying not to repeat the other solutions that have already been given. Looks like you have quite the buffet of choices here. :)

Comment: thanks for the explanation - it works now , and will help me understand the "this" and "children" issue. but I must say that @Ohgodwhy seems to me more correct (from a web-designer POV) - even if not always viable.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you were trying to select ".meta" as a descendant of ".meta2" and it isn't. The line:

```
jQuery(".meta", this).fadeIn(400);
```

Says to select ".meta" elements within the context of `this` - which in this case is the ".meta2" element that the `.mouseenter()` function was bound to. But ".meta" is not a child of ".meta2". You can simply remove the `this` context as follows:

```
jQuery(".meta").fadeIn(400);
```

And it will work as shown in this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VFwxN/6/

However, that will fade in *all* elements with the class ".meta". If you want to use this on a page that has multiple elements with that class you should instead use the `.prev()` method to select the div that immediately precedes whichever ".meta2" div was hovered over:

```
jQuery(this).prev(".meta").fadeIn(400);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VFwxN/10/

Obviously this applies specifically to the html structure you've used where ".meta2" and ".meta" are siblings.

Supplying a selector to `.prev()` means it will only select the previous element if it matches that selector (otherwise it won't match anything - it doesn't keep looking further back).

Comment: thanks a lot . I somehow did not see your whole solution  (you all responded roughly at the same time ..) the .prev() selector is great for using . I can not upvote now (little privilege) but you sure deserve the vote . I will return to do so when i can ..

Answer (score 3):

He might want to use "this" because there's going to be multiple meta2's that need this hover function.

I've updated the jsfiddle here ->

> http://jsfiddle.net/VFwxN/7/

I restructured the HTML to reflect what you were trying to do with your JS.

The issue is that

> jQuery(".meta",this).fadeIn(400);

Was looking for an element with the class of 'meta' that resided within 'this', this is the element that invoked the action. in your case, it was ->

> jQuery(".mas").mouseenter(function(){

Correcting the DOM structure allows you to refer to meta within the scope of meta2. If you can't restructure your DOM and you don't need to use 'this' to refer to the mouseover element, then you can use the solution that Rick provided.

Comment: Alternatively the solution I provided uses `this` with the current html structure...

Comment: Yep sure does! Looks like there's a thousand different ways to cook this egg. I like your post, I'll upvote you for the use of .prev() and selector comparison.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy exactly - I do have multiple - see my EDIT I

Comment: @Ohgodwhy - thanks , your solution works perfectly . Structuring the Dom is a possibility for me - but more important is understanding how to target. will give +1 as soon as I will have the privilege to do so. (sorry I can not accept both)

Comment: +1 thanks again - you have all been extremely  helpful - unfortunatly I can only accept one ..